# Relationship between coarse objects, separated objects, and sheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

I would like to better understand the relationship between quasitopoi and topoi. Here are two relationships that I am aware of:

1. Given a local topos $E \to S$, i.e. such that $S$ is equivalent to the subtopos of $j$-sheaves for a Lawvere-Tierney operator $j$ in $E$, the category of $j$-separated objects of $E$ is a quasitopos. These are the "concrete" objects of $E$, i.e. those whose equality predicates are "(co)discrete".
2. On the other hand, given a quasitopos $Q$, the full subcategory of *coarse objects* (those that perceive epic monos as isomorphisms) is a topos.

**My question is:** when looking at a local topos $E\to S$ for which $Q$ is the corresponding quasitopos of concrete objects, I am wondering whether the topos of coarse objects in $Q$ is just $S$. This seems to be alluded to by Mike Shulman on the [the n-Category Café here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/10/cohesive_toposes.html#c035237), but I was wondering how I would go about proving something like this.

**Bonus question:** a similar situation arises in realizability, where we take a pca $A$ internal to a topos $S$, and consider the realizability topos $E$. This is not a topos over $S$, but nonetheless, the global sections functor $\Gamma : E \to S$ has a fully faithful right adjoint $\nabla:S\hookrightarrow E$, which behaves a lot like the embedding of "codiscrete" objects in a local topos except for the fact that $\Gamma\dashv\nabla$ does not have an additional left adjoint. In any case, you can speak of the objects of $E$ that are separated in the sense of the embedding $S\hookrightarrow E$ and these are the assemblies. My bonus question is, whether in this case also, the "coarse" assemblies are simply the codiscrete ones arising from $S$.